# Scripting FileSystemObject creates Runtime 429 error on Windows

Tags: excel, vba

Am I missing a reference object? Trying to retrieve a list of files in a directory and have them show in a sheet.

Also, would it be possible to get the directory location from a specific cell in the file?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\VBA Folder")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name

    i = i + 1

Next oFile

End Sub
```

Here:

`Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

> Runtime error 429 on a Windows machine.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp lol Thanks!  That is why I am thinking maybe I'm missing a reference or DLL or something.

Comment: As far as I know, `Scripting.FileSystemObject` should be available on all Windows machines, so I don't know what you are missing. I tested by copy-and-pasting into a new spreadsheet and it worked oob. Maybe you need elevated permissions??

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I will check that. Maybe open the file as admin?

Comment: Maybe this will help: 
[Error: ActiveX Component Can't Create Object Scripting.FileSystemObject](//stackoverflow.com/q/5457000)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  No joy. Have the Scripting.FileSystemObject in the registry.

Comment: Have you tried early binding? Tools/References, dig up the scripting runtime library, add it, `Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject` (please drop these `o` prefixes), and `Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Works?

Comment: WORKED! Thanks so much!!! @MathieuGuindon

Comment: I bet it's removing the Hungarian Notation that fixed it! ;-)

Comment: One last thing, would it be possible to use a cell reference to pull in the filepath? something like, 

```Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder Sheets("Variables").Range("B10")```

Comment: Yes, but that requires parentheses: `Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(Sheets(Variables).Range(B10))`

Answer (score 1):

There's little to no reason at all to late-bind the `Scripting` library - it's present (same identical version) on every single Windows box out there, and won't work on a Mac whether you late-bind it or not.

Tools/References, add the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library to your project, and then declare the actual data types for your object variables; you'll get compile-time validation and intellisense/autocompletion (good-bye error 438!) for all member calls.

Early binding is your friend. Declare `As Scrpiting.FileSystemObject`, and then just `New` up the object instead of hitting the registry to resolve the `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"` ProgID with `CreateObject`:

```
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Or have a `With` block *whith*old the object reference, and then you don't even need a local variable for it:

```
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    '....
End With
```